# Drupal Implementing some HTML within a node?

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-forms, drupal-form-submission

I have a node/content that outputs like a form that is available to guests to add jobs to.  I would like to implement this HTML inside of the form to reduce spam:

```
<div style="POSITION: absolute; TOP: -1000px; LEFT: -1000px">
    <label for="address">If you see this, Leave Empty:</label>
        <input id="address" name="address" />
</div>
<div style="display: none;">
    <label for="username">If you see this, Leave Blank:</label>
        <input id="username" name="username" />
</div>
```

I kind of need this within the `<form>` tag.

Now when the form gets submitted, I'd like to be able to check for this and be sure both inputs are empty, and if they are empty, the form should be submitted, otherwise, if either is filled in with anything, it should not be allowed to be submitted.  I did this on another, Non-Drupal, site and it eliminated the SPAM on that form completely.  But now I'm on a Drupal site, and would like to understand how to do this via a node.

I don't currently have FTP Access, however, I do have complete Admin Access on the Drupal site, so if there is a way to do this via Drupal that would be preferable.  Is there a module that will do something similar to this that I can add as a field on that node?

Any help to point me in the right direction on getting started for this is greatly appreciated.  Also, I have the Devel Module installed if that helps...

Answer (score 0):

I believe the [spamicide](https://drupal.org/project/spamicide) module does the equivalent of what you are wanting to do